# How does Chernoff-Hoeffding bound with limited independence reduce to the usual generic CH bound with complete independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

As the title might suggest, I am referring to this paper [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~srin/PDF/ch-bounds.pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esrin/PDF/ch-bounds.pdf) , titled : Chernoff-Hoeffding Bounds for Application with Limited Independence.

The theorem in question is Theorem 5 of the paper, specifically the following
[image]

If I wish to reduce back to the generic CH-bound, I would then set $k = n$, where $n$ is the number of $r.v$. But now base on the theorem, I could (potentially) get a better bound than the generic CH-bound. I feel like I am misunderstanding some nuances involving this theorem.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated

Cheers